# Get the whole index of Maven Central

Tags: java, maven, maven-2

I am developing a private repository by java. I want to use maven central as proxy repository. So I want the whole artifact list or maven central repository index. How can I get all artifact list or maven central repository index programmatically?

Comment: Why are you doing this?  Why don't you just deploy / use Artifactory or Nexus?

Comment: I need a private repository developed by me. I don't want to use Artifactory or Nexus or Archiva. I find the index file here http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/.index/ but how can I parse this?

Comment: Why? Archiva is Apache License complete open source?

Comment: Archiva is too heavy to me to edit. I want a simple repository with simple feature. So I want to develop it from scratch. But that repository must be multi-tenant.

Comment: I hope that you are not doing this on company time.  Your stated reasons for developing a new repo codebase from scratch don't make economic sense to me.